# Control my Android application on the tablet through universal remote

Tags: android

I have an Android tablet and have an application installed on it.

Now i need to control this application on the tablet through my universal remote (which will be paired with my tablet using Bluetooth).

The simple scenario I want to explain here:
I have a listbox on my app with some items on it and by default very first item will be selected. Now when I press a down button on my remote the next item should be selected in the listbox.

Is it possible in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very much possible.

There is an existing bluetooth profile by name AVRCP (Audio/Video Remote Control Profile) in Bluetooth which fits your usecase.

https://www.bluetooth.org/Building/HowTechnologyWorks/ProfilesAndProtocols/AVRCP.htm

Comment: i think you misunderstood my problem. My problem is, i want to create my app in a way that it could be controlled by remote control.

Comment: I see 3 major things here.- Universal remote sending std cmds [up/down] - transport type b/w app and remote. - cmds to android event translation. Majority r/c and phones are equipped with BT and AVRCP profile and ur app shud just listen for the events coming from the remote side. when ever the app receievs such an event with the event type, it should take necessary action. this is one way of controlling the app by remote control. I might have still misunderstood your use-case though ? could you elaborate more on " i want to create my app in a way that it could be controlled by remote control"